# Does Location Services' `getLastKnownLocation()` check phone's current GPS location?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

Some resources say `getLastKnownLocation()` merely gives a location of some previous app's Location Change Listener.

But one thing I feel is missing from the conversation -- if the phone has GPS enabled, isn't this GPS tracking/updating as the phone moves? So if I call `getLastKnownLocation()`, isn't it getting the current GPS from the phone's constantly-updated GPS?

If so, then why do people warn against using it / accuse it of potentially getting a "stale" location? If the GPS is being tracked / updated, and `getLastKnownLocation()` makes a one-time grab of it's current position, what makes `getLastKnownLocation()` bad?

What am I mistaken about the `Locations` service or GPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) says: `Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider.`

Also, about the "out of date location": `This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.` ("This" refers to getting the last known location).

Also, taken from [LocationProvider docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html):
`Each provider has a set of criteria under which it may be used; for example, some providers require GPS hardware and visibility to a number of satellites; others require the use of the cellular radio, or access to a specific carrier's network, or to the internet. They may also have different battery consumption characteristics or monetary costs to the user.`

> if the phone has GPS enabled, isn't this GPS tracking/updating as the phone moves?

Well, it is, but not constantly. This has to do with battery consumption, if the phone was constantly updating the GPS location, the battery life would suffer a lot. The GPS location is usually updated when some app requests it. But even that request is not guaranteed to succeed. For example, suppose your going into a tunnel. Some application requests to update the GPS coordinates right before entering the tunnel and it succeeds. Now, you've entered the tunnel, which is 5km long. Most probably your device won't be able to get a GPS fix from the tunnel, so for the next 5km (at least) `getLastKnownLocation()` will return an outdated value, **since the devices last known location was at the entrance of the tunnel**.

What you could do is explicitly request to update the GPS location, that however might take some time and there are no guarantees that it will succeed.

Comment: `The GPS location is usually updated when some app requests it` - is `getLastKnownLocation()` not requesting it, and thus telling it to update? Then how / when else does it get updated?

Comment: The alternative in Android tutorials is to implement `LocationListener` - but all this does it make a call-back for when the GPS is updated - it's not itself updating GPS. So how is using `LocationListener` (the only other option mentioned for getting GPS) better than just calling `getLastKnownLocation()`? The docs make it seem neither actually updates GPS - `getLastKnown` just grabs whatever last-GPS read, and `LocationListener` gives you a way to be told when GPS is updated. Btw, I appreciate your time in helping me with this.

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation()` simply gets the last known location, it doesn't update it. It gets updated when some application says "Hey Android, please update the GPS location". When some application calls `getLastKnownLocation()` it's basically saying: "Hey Android, could you please tell me what's the most recent known location?"., it doesn't ask for the location to be updated. That "most recent known location" is stored somewhere in the Android OS.

Comment: If you want to say: "Hey Android, please update the GPS location", follow this tutorial:

[LocationStrategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

Scroll down to where it says `Requesting Location Updates`, there is a code sample and explanation of exactly what you asked in the 2nd comment.

Comment: fyi - I'm trying to stay with using the Google Play Location Services way of doing it -- I assume using Google Play Location Services does not invalidate your info? Top of your link gives a warning about it's contents and suggests using `Location Services`

Comment: Here is a more appropriate one: [Receive Location Updated](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). Scroll down to `Connect to Location Services`.

Comment: Ok so calling `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` and passing in a request parameters/interval settings is actually going to request the GPS update. I see... So `getLastLocation()` is essentially depending on other apps calling `requestLocationUpdates`? In my app, I just have a single point (button click) where I'd like to display GPS. I guess I should request updates and keep assigning a variable to the latest-updated GPS as the callback is called over the interval - and then when I need the GPS just access that variable. <- reasonable way to use functionality?

Comment: That would work, but you could also use `getLastKnownLocation()` directly. Imagine the following scenario: you request a location update, it succeeds, your variable gets updated. 30 seconds after, some other app requests a new location, it succeeds. 10 seconds after that you use your variable to get the location, however, **it is not the most recent one**.

Comment: So I guess this is optimal: request updates periodically. Then -- *just* before I need to use the location - call `getLastKnownLocation()`. Worst case scenario, updates never worked anyway, and I'll get some out-dated location. But if my updates are going through, I get the latest location which was updated by my request. And in case some other app updates location after me, I still get that more recent location. Issue: Is there a way to know if GPS is not updating / likely badly out-of-date?

Comment: I would say yes. But be careful with "request updates periodically", since requesting a new GPS location is quite expensive when it comes to battery consumption. I would suggest you doing some more research on how often to request a new location, so that there's a balance between accuracy and battery consumption.

Comment: is there a way to know how long-ago GPS was updated? That would be very handy. If for example it was updated 12 minutes ago, it's likely perfectly fine... if 100 days ago, maybe not

Comment: Yes, the `Location` object returned by `getLastKnownLocation()` includes a timestamp of that fix. Just call [getElapsedRealtimeNanos()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getElapsedRealtimeNanos()) on the `Location` object.

Comment: there's not just a way to say "Please update GPS just once right now with what you can"? We have to set these intervals?

Comment: You can always just stop the location updates once you `onLocationChanged()` method gets called. Again, refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) (scroll down to `Stop Location Updates`).

Comment: By checking the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/location/java/android/location/LocationRequest.java) the default interval is 60 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You have the assumption "if the phone has GPS enabled, isn't this GPS tracking/updating as the phone moves". This assumption is incorrect. The GPS functionality takes up a lot of battery life so it should be used sparingly and almost certainly not all the time.

Comment: I'm considering differences between implementing `LocationListener` and checking for updates, and merely calling `getLastKnownLocation()`. Correct me if I'm wrong: `getLastKnownLocation()` just grabs whatever the GPS currently thinks location is, whereas implementing `LocationListener` makes it so you can be alerted (overriding methods + listening) when GPS gets a new location reading. But neither options in and of themselves are telling the GPS to update - they both only work by reading what GPS gives them, first one does it once on-demand, other is alerted of any changes. All that correct?

Comment: "getLastKnownLocation() just grabs whatever the GPS currently thinks location i" is not correct. It only gets the last position when whatever `LocationProvider` happens to be running or was the last to run. I think @ILUXONCHIK does a good job explaining more about the provider.